# Equalize subdivision of a mesh

Tags: mesh, topology

Say I have a mesh with inconsistent subdivision. There are some areas with really large faces and no details, and other areas with lots of tightly packed detail. For example, a building with detailed windows with window sills and trim on one side, and no windows on another.

I would like to subdivide or otherwise cut the large blank faces to be at about the same level of detail/face size as the detailed areas, but without further subdividing the detail. It does not have to be exact, and I don't care if it causes triangles, ngons, or other such bad topology. The goal is to able to standardize the mesh for purposes of vertex colors and the pointiness attribute.

Here is an example. On the right is what I have, on the left is what I'd like to turn it into.
[image]

The meshes are too complex to do it by hand. Is there any way to automate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select one of the edges that's too long and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to **Select Similar > Length**. Then you can subdivide these edges as many times as needed.

[image: Selecting edges by length and subdividing to selectively increase the mesh density]

The number of subdivision cuts can be specified in the Operator Panel:

[image: Specifying the number of subdivision cuts]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

- For simple topology you may be able to dissolve edges.  Then use loop cuts again.
- Loop Tools, which is an addon,  can also evenly space adjacent loops

[image]

- Remesh Modifier does this well.  This is often useful for Text to Mesh.
- Slightly off topic, but how do you work well with such a jarring UI theme? – NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ 9 mins ago

Comment: Slightly off topic, but how do you work well with such a jarring UI theme?

Comment: @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ lololol...Thanks for asking what we've all been wondering. I just figured this is what it looks like when a bezier-slinger goes atomic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then either type in the number of cuts, or scroll up on your mouse wheel to get the number of divisions that you want.

[image]